# After Move project from one server to another server site not working

Tags: magento2

i have **move my project from one server to another server** then after site give **500 error** .before move i have change base URL , i also change database configuration . still give **500** in front end and back end please guide me for resolve my issue

Comment: Check your .htaccess file.

Comment: i have check .htaccess , still facing same issue

Comment: Remove var folder and check again.

Comment: My issue resolve , actually issue with database , thanks